# Java jar files(Java libraries) to generate multiline chart graph that i can i use in my rails application?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails

Hello friends,
              Is there any jar file that i can use in my rails application to generate multi-line graph in pdf files. Or any library to generate multi-line chart image so that i can paste that image in my pdf file.

Answer (score 2):

There is JFreeChart as a Java Library for any kind of charts. Maybe it suits your needs.
With it you can generate chart PNGs. I used it in a reporting application, which included a PDF export feature.

[JFreeChart Samples](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html)

Comment: So in PDf file u attach these png files? Your Application is based on Java technology or ruby on rails?

Comment: JFreeChart is a Java API for generating charts. It's a good API, but needs some time to learn.